# What is the correct URI for connecting to the Websocket server in my case?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, proxy

I am using proxyPass to redirect my websocket inquiries as such :

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass /rooms/325 wss://cdn.dummy.com:443/rooms/325
ProxyPassReverse /rooms/325 wss://cdn.dummy.com:443/rooms/325
```

Given than my current domain is foo.com , I cannot get connected using `https ://foo.com/rooms/325` and I cannot get connected to it using `wss://foo.com/rooms/325`
I am given to understand that I cannot use https for my websocket transmission and yet I did not define anywhere that protocol wss should be handled, so I am quite confused as in my client what address I should use to get connected through proxyPass.

What is the correct URI for connecting to the Websocket server in my case?